# Memory alocated for Creating object inside a function?

Tags: c++, function, oop, memory

As objects are created from same class. Each object contains the variable defined in the class except those which are defined in the methods of that class. Variable in functions of the same object are shared memory right? If we have a function where we create an object of the same class, where will be the reference reside? Isnt that reference be shared too?

Comment: This is really confusing, and I'm having trouble seeing what is being asked. Could you please post some code to illustrate what you are saying at least?

Comment: Edit your question to include a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Methods are no different from any other function with regard to memory use: local variables are created when execution reaches their declaration, and (unless `static`) they are destroyed, and their memory reclaimed, when [execution leaves the block it](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration).  (This happens, at latest, when the function returns.)  There is no connection to the `this` object or any of its members.  Nor does the variable having the same type as the method’s class make any difference.

In some sense, that does make the memory “shared”: it will be rapidly reclaimed and (typically) reused.  But that’s nothing special, and don’t think that it means more than it does: if a method is recursive, or invoked concurrently by more than one thread, each copy has its own locals—again, just like any other function.

Finally, any function or method can allocate memory dynamically; the lifetime and sharing of the allocated object may be unrelated to that of the *variable* used to refer to it.

Comment: Sir you cleared things very well but there is one point that i still need answer for. Explain below